# Use photo file from one project to another project in the same solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

i have solution where are three project (Intranet, Site, and Data). In Intranet i have form where I add new Restaurant object (name, description, photo and etc.). Photos are saved in Path Intranet/wwwroot/images/items and link to the photo is saved in database like this:

```
wwwroot\\images\\items\\<photo_name>
```

When i want display photo in this same project i use:

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="@Url.Content("~/images/items/" + @item.Photo2)" alt="">
```

But if i want display this photo in other project (Site), it doesn't work, since they are in other project. It is possible change src in Site Project to display photos from another project? Or is better way to do this?

Comment: Put common data in a network folder or a shared folder on your machine instead of part of the project.

Comment: A common solution for sharing a resource between multiple projects is saving photos in the database.

Comment: Ok, i create shared folder and i save file in this "..\\wwwroot\\images\\items" (Controller Class) -> it work ok. But i want get the file `<img class="img-responsive" src="@Url.Content("../wwwroot/images/items/" + @item.Photo2)" alt="">` the photo is doesn't appear

Answer (score 1):

One of the solutions might be to use a [virtual folder](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/308150/how-to-create-a-virtual-directory-on-an-existing-web-site-to-a-folder) that points to the right physical folder of the source project. This folder will act as own folder of the *Site* project and you can point to its content in a similar way as you do in the *Intranet*.

i.e. if *Intranet* path for images is

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\images\items 
                          ^^^^^
```

create a new virtual directory `/items` under `/images` of *Site* project in IIS and point to the same source directory of your other project

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\images\items
```

This will let you to access same images as `~/images/items/` in the *Site* project.

Another approach would be to create an [image handler](https://translate.google.de/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fblog.ppedv.de%2Fpost%2FImage-Handler-in-ASPNET-Core) that will programmatically access required file and output it to the browser as an image.

Comment: It's perfect solution for me. I create additional folder named "resources" and i save in this using path "..\\resources\\images\\items" (Controller Class). But when i get photo using `<img class="img-responsive" src="@Url.Content("../resources/images/items/" + @item.Photo2)" alt="">` it doesn't work. In browser path looks ok: https://localhost:44313/resources/images/items/p11.png

Comment: `..` stands for parent folder, in the path `localhost:44313/resources` there is no parent to resources, i.e. remove `..`

Comment: I remove and it still doesn't work. In main directory i have Directory: Intranet, Site, Data and Resources <- where i got photo and Firma.sln file. Path to photo looks ok, but it still doesn't work

Comment: Open page source in the browser and see what path was generated by @Url.Content()

Comment: Is generated `src="wwwroot/images/items/p11.png"`, and arror that can't find ``localhost:44313/resources/images/items/p11.png``

Comment: There is something unclear in your setup, but if required path is `localhost:44313/resources/images/items/p11.png` and it works in the browser, then you can hit this path without @Url.Content as `<img src="/resources/images/items/@item.Photo2" />`. This should render in the browser `<img src="/resources/images/items/p11.png" />` which should work on the website with the url of `localhost:44313`